# Difference between Airbus and Boeing planes, width for economy seats

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, seating

I came to know that even within the economy class, there are two-three options for the traveller, but I don't know if that translates to bigger area for your seat. I travelled in Qatar Airways Boeing's few months back and both of them had 17" which I guess is the standard. From BOM to Doha,Qatar it was Boeing 777-300ER  and from Doha to CPT, South Africa it was the Boeing 797-8 Dreamliner . IF it was an Airbus would the seat width have been be a bit wider or that's standard for Economy class configuration. If memory serves right, it was 3-5-3 in the first configuration and 3-4-3 in the latter long haul flight.

So looking to know how different is it in Airbus on Economy class.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that all planes of the same maker/model will have the same seats; that's often not the case, especially on larger planes.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to downvote this question.  For someone new to flying, it's a great question.

Comment: Hi again Shirish.  As others have explained, each plane is built-out *specifically for the airline*.  So for example flying AA is sickening as they generally squeeze in as many seats as possible; flying Emirates is generally (a tiny, tiny bit) better as they generally have a policy of spacing out seats (a tiny, tiny bit) more.  Note that anyway it's all-but impossible to know what specific aircraft, or what specific brand of aircraft, you're going to get - so forget it.  Airbus is better all round than Boeing, but you won't be able to choose.

Comment: Overwhelmingly, I urge you to get a aisle not middle or window seat.  That overwhelms any slight difference between the seat layout the airline has chosen.  The only way you can be somewhat sure of getting a seat assignment is if it's the same airline on both your legs between BOM - europe - Montreal.  Unfortunately you'll likely be stuck with Turkish - so the whole question is unfortunately for you moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't going to see a specific difference between Boeing and Airbus for this. Every aircraft can be configured differently depending on the airline's wishes and it has little to do with who makes the plane.

The best thing to do for this kind of information is to check a website like [seatguru.com](https://www.seatguru.com/). You can find the seat map for the aircraft operating a particular flight and note the pitch (legroom) and width in the top right of the page.

[image: seatguru size chart]

Note that airlines often have different configurations of the same model aircraft. For one of your examples, Qatar has three configurations of the 777-300ER: [V1](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Qatar_Airways/Qatar_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER.php), [V2](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Qatar_Airways/Qatar_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER_V2.php), and [V3](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Qatar_Airways/Qatar_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER_V3.php). V1 and V2 are a 3-4-3 layout in economy with 17" width seats, while V3 is a 3-3-3 layout with 18.5" seats. You can often see which configuration the airline expects to use by attempting to match the seat map on the airline website with the map on SeatGuru, but note that the airline does not guarantee this (they, in fact, do not guarantee the type of aircraft at all) and may change to a different aircraft or seating configuration at any time.